# Inequality that holds for an arbitrary element of a Hilbert space is also true for an element of a dense subset

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with dense subset $D \subseteq H$. Let $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^{n}$ and $g$ be elements of $H$ and $C > 0$ such that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \vert \langle g,f_k \rangle \vert^2 > C \| g \|^2.
$$
Now I don't understand the following statement: Since $D$ is dense in $H$, there exists $h \in D$ such that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \vert \langle h,f_k \rangle \vert^2 > C \| h \|^2.
$$
How can I formally show this?

Comment: Since $D$ is dense, there is a sequence $\{h_k\} \subset D$ with $h_k \to g$.

Comment: @gerw This is clear to me of course, this is just the definition of being dense.

Comment: Now suppose that the inequality below fails for all $h_k$...

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be such that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \vert\langle g,f_i\rangle\vert^2 - C\Vert g\Vert^2\geq\varepsilon$$
Now let $\{h_k\}$ be a sequence in $H$ such that $h_k\to g$ as $k\to\infty$. Then, by continuity of the norm and of the scalar product we also have
$$ \Vert h_k\Vert^2\to \Vert g\Vert^2, \quad \vert\langle h_m,f_i\rangle\vert^2\to \vert\langle g,f_i\rangle\vert^2$$
for all $i=1,\ldots, n$. The sum is finite therefore we have
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^n \vert\langle h_k,f_i\rangle\vert^2 - C\Vert h_k\Vert^2 \bigg] = 
\sum_{i=1}^n \vert\langle g,f_i\rangle\vert^2 - C\Vert g\Vert^2\geq\varepsilon$$
In particular, for $k$ big enough we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \vert\langle h_k,f_i\rangle\vert^2 - C\Vert h_k\Vert^2 > \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$and so 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \vert\langle h_k,f_i\rangle\vert^2 > C\Vert h_k\Vert^2$$